# How can i update the value in the list of ceiling using resttemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

1.there is the json list for the controller and the data that what i've been used

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "cardname" : "visa gold",
    "cardnumber": "1254***548**54",
    "status" : true,
    "opposed" : false,
    "issueDate" : "21-06-2021",
    "cardbalance" : 200000,
    "validitydate" : "25-06-2021",
    "experationdate" : "30-06-2023",
    "onlinepayment" : true,
    "contactless" : true,
    "withdrawal" : false,
    "ceiling" : [{
      "maxValue" : 10000,
      "minValue" : 500,
      "value" : 100000,
      "currency" : "MAD",
      "type" : "paiment"
    }]
```

2.and there is my restcontroller code

```
    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public Ceiling update(@RequestParam Integer id, Card card){
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Card>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Card>>() {};
        ResponseEntity<List<Card>> resp = restTemplate.exchange(GET_CARD, HttpMethod.GET, resp, responseType);
        List<Card> list = resp.getBody();
        return ;
    }
```

the problem is the put doesn't work the value in the list ceiling , they give me the error : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present]

Comment: Note that you should check your post is nicely formatted, otherwise it is likely to attract down and close votes or at least repell people who'd be willing to help otherwise. I did it for you this time but it should be your concern right from the start. You might also want to read [ask] (again) and add some more explanation and actually ask a question (right now you're just stating what you are trying to do).

Comment: What is the request URL you are sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message,

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer parameter 'id' is not present]

which says the `id` request parameter is not present in the URL.

If you are passing the `id` as an request parameter, then the URL should be like  `/update?id=12345` and controller method should defined like follows,

```
@PutMapping("/update")
public Card update(@RequestParam(value="id") Integer id, Card card){

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<Card> request = new HttpEntity<>(card);
    ResponseEntity<Card> response = restTemplate.exchange(GET_CARD, HttpMethod.GET, request, Card.class);
    return response.getBody(); 
}
```

**NOTE :** you have not mentioned any information about the relationship between the `Card` and `Ceiling` entities. So just assuming that the `GET_CARD` endpoint is updating the `card` which we are passing through REST call and returning the updated `Card` with the response, I have modified the method body as above.

And if you need to send the `id` as a path variable, then the URL should be like `update/{id}` and controller method should be like,

```
@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
public Card update(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Card card){
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpEntity<Card> request = new HttpEntity<>(card);
    ResponseEntity<Card> response = restTemplate.exchange(GET_CARD, HttpMethod.GET, request, Card.class);
    return response.getBody(); 
}
```

Comment: what i should do in the return statement for update the value of ceiling and give me the result ?

Comment: @lamyaa it is not clear what you mean by `Ceiling` is (Object or an Operation) and the relationship between `Card` and the  `Ceiling`. With an assumption, I have updated my answer.

Comment: the relation between card and ceiling is one to one " one card have a ceiling " , and I need just to update the value in the ceiling list and also the maxValue and the ceiling is an object not an operation

Answer (score 0):

you have your card Object as a Parameter which contains the response of the json object. You can update the values using the card object.